# Homebrew GCC5 Installation error on Mac OSX 10.9.3

Tags: c++, osx-mavericks, gcc5

I'm trying to install gcc5 on OSX 10.9.3 (Mavericks) using homebrew (brew install gcc5 ) and getting the following errors. I'm able to install the same on OSX 10.11.1 (El Capitan) on a separate machine. However due to other software compatibility issues, upgrading the operating system is something I'd like to avoid. Couldn't find any known bug for this problem. Any advice would be appreciated.

```
Error: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/Formula/gcc5.rb:5: syntax error, unexpected '<'
<!DOCTYPE html>
 ^
/Library/Caches/Homebrew/Formula/gcc5.rb:6: syntax error, unexpected '<'
<html lang="en" class="">
 ^
/Library/Caches/Homebrew/Formula/gcc5.rb:6: syntax error, unexpected keyword_class, expecting end-of-input
<html lang="en" class="">
                     ^
Please report this bug:
    https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/wiki/troubleshooting
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
/usr/local/Library/Homebrew/formulary.rb:65:in `klass'
/usr/local/Library/Homebrew/formulary.rb:50:in `get_formula'
/usr/local/Library/Homebrew/formulary.rb:198:in `factory'
/usr/local/Library/Homebrew/extend/ARGV.rb:12:in `block in formulae'
/usr/local/Library/Homebrew/extend/ARGV.rb:12:in `map'
/usr/local/Library/Homebrew/extend/ARGV.rb:12:in `formulae'
/usr/local/Library/Homebrew/cmd/install.rb:27:in `install'
/usr/local/Library/brew.rb:131:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Similar problem with the armadillo C++ library on Mavericks

Comment: The system requests you to report the bug; have you done so?  It looks like the code is parsing an HTML document but is not expecting to do so.